# Django: How to fill several empty cells in a table

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-views, django-templates

I'm currently just learning Django and I'm doing electronic grade book. I have tried lots of things, but nothing helped.

I need the teacher to see the table with the current tasks, given to a certain class. Two of the columns of this table, relevant to my problem,
are the following: "tasks" and "marks", each mark is related to a certain task.

Thus, I have the One-to-many relation between classes Mark and Task (models/views/urls attached by the link):

https://www.codepile.net/pile/anxGqm7W

In my template I have written forloop, so that each mark corresponds to a certain task:

https://www.codepile.net/pile/KRBbvmRG

Now in my column "Marks" I see all marks, related to their tasks. However, not all tasks are rated. So some cells of "Marks" column are empty (" " when I look at the code of the page in my browser). I need
to somehow fill them with the "Add mark" link to the admin page, so that the teacher could add mark.
So I need to have some cells in this colums, filled with marks (already done and working) and some should not be empty, but should have links to redirect to another page.

Here comes the problem. I cannot find any solution to do it. For instance, I changed my template like this:

```
<td>{% for mark in marks_queryset %}
        {% if mark.task_id.task_name == task.task_name %}
        {{ mark.final_score }}
        {% else %}
        Any information
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </td>
```

But it certainly doesn't work, filling every cell in "Marks" column with infinite "Any information" words for every mark, which isn't related to a certain task.
Looks like I can't see the logic, the foorloop will not work here. Unfortunately, my One to many relation doesn't allow me to use the attribute of the related class in that case, like I did in other columns.

I will be really grateful for your help, even if you just advise, what I can google to find the solution.

Comment: This seems overly complex. Try instead of creating a `marks_queryset` and then checking against the task name for a match, pull related marks from the task i.e. `task.mark_set.all()` and iterate over the selection

Comment: Also foreign keys link to an another model instance, not an id. Hence, naming the field e.g. `task_id` is a misnomer, it should just be task

Comment: Thanks, I will try it

Comment: The only thing, which has worked. Maybe it is not a valid one, but I am happy: I deleted marks_queryset in view, as you advised, in my template I just have written `{% if task.mark_set.get %} {{ task.mark_set.get }} {% else %} Finally I got it {% endif %}` And I added __str__ method to Mark class in models.py, so that it shows the final score of a mark.
Also, this thing works: `task.mark_set.get.final_score`